# Mocking single methods in Go

Tags: testing, go, mocking

In Go, how can I mock an interface without having to implement every method? Let's say I have a `Car` interface and a `Corolla` struct that implements that interface:

```
type Car interface {
    changeTire()
    startEngine()
    ....
    refuel()
}

type Corolla struct {
    ...
}

func (c Corolla) changeTire() {...}

func (c Corolla) startEngine() {...}

func (c Corolla) refuel() {...}
```

Let's say I also have a `Garage` struct that depends on `Car`:

```
type Garage struct {
    MyCar Car
}

func (g Garage) PrepareCarToDrive() {
    g.MyCar.changeTire()
    g.MyCar.refuel()
    g.MyCar.startEngine()
}
```

And I want to test `Garage`, so I create a `MockCar` that implements `Car`

```
type MockCar struct {
    ...
}

func (c MockCar) changeTire() {...}

func (c MockCar) startEngine() {...}

func (c MockCar) refuel() {...}
```

Now I have tests that test  `PrepareCarToDrive` and I use the `MockCar`:

```
func TestGarage_PrepareCarToDrive_DoesSomething(t *testing.T) {
    mockCar := MockCar{}
    garageUnderTest := Garage{}
    garageUnderTest.MyCar = mockCar

    // some other setup

    // when Garage calls mockCar.changeTire(), should do X
    ...
}

func TestGarage_PrepareCarToDrive_DoesSomethingElse(t *testing.T) {
    mockCar := MockCar{}
    garageUnderTest := Garage{}
    garageUnderTest.MyCar = mockCar

    // some other setup 
    // when Garage calls mockCar.changeTire(), should do Y
    ...
}
```

My question is, how can I have `mockCar` do different things each test? I know that I can create a different mock implementation of `Car` for each test. But this will get out of hand really quickly as I add more methods to `Car`.

I'm coming from a Java background so I'm looking for something like Mockito that will let me mock just the methods I need for each test.

What is the best way to do this in Go? Or am I missing something more fundamental?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you embed the interface type itself in your mock struct, you can then only implement the methods you need. For example:

```
type MockCar struct {
    Car
    ...
}

func (c MockCar) changeTire() {...}
```

Even though your struct only implements `changeTire` explicitly, it still satisfies the interface because the `Car` field provides the rest. This works as long as you don't try to call any of the unimplemented methods (which will cause a panic because `Car` is `nil`)

Comment: That's the way I was forgetting!  Though worth noting, you could throw something like Corolla into the interface to gain default implementations for things you don't override.

That said, this doesn't provide the ability to define per-test function overrides, though it could be combined with my function-field style below to do so.

Comment: Great thanks. A somewhat related question: IIUC I can't setup the embedding **inside** my test method. If I have several test methods and several Mocks, what is the best way to bundle them? Create separate go files with a test + mock pair in each?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You might want to post a whole new question with some details.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest method is to use some base implementation as an embed for your test structure, and only override the method you're testing.  Example using your types:

```
type MockCar struct {
    Corolla // embedded, so the method implementations of Corolla get promoted
}

// overrides the Corolla implementation
func (c MockCar) changeTire() {
    // test stuff
}

// refuel() and startEngine(), since they are not overridden, use Corolla's implementation
```

https://play.golang.org/p/q3_L1jf4hk

---

An alternative, if you need a different implementation per test, is to use a mock with function fields:

```
type MockCar struct {
    changeTireFunc func()
    startEngineFunc func()
    ....
    refuelFunc func()
}

func (c MockCar) changeTire() {
    if c.changeTireFunc != nil {
        c.changeTireFunc()
    }
}

func (c MockCar) startEngine() {
    if c.startEngineFunc != nil {
        c.startEngineFunc()
    }
}

func (c MockCar) refuel() {
    if c.refuelFunc != nil {
        c.refuelFunc()
    }
}

// test code

func TestGarage_PrepareCarToDrive_DoesSomething(t *testing.T) {
    // let's say we require refuel(), but the default implementation is fine
    // changeTire(), however, requires a mocked testing implementation
    // and we don't need startEngine() at all
    mockCar := MockCar{
        changeTireFunc: func() {
            // test functionality
        },
        refuelFunc: Corolla.refuel,
    }
    garageUnderTest := Garage{}
    garageUnderTest.MyCar = mockCar

    // some other setup

    // when Garage calls mockCar.changeTire(), should do X
    ...
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lf7ny-lUCS

This style is a bit less useful when you're trying to use another type's methods as the default implementation, but can be very useful if you have some stand-alone functions that can be used as your default or test implementation, or if a trivial return is acceptable for functions you haven't specifically mocked (like the behavior of the mocked `startEngine()` in the example above, which does nothing at all when called because the `startEngineFunc` field is nil).

You can also, if you wish, bake the default implementation (like a call to `(Corolla{}).startEngine()`) into the mock method if the relevant function field is nil.  This allows you the best of both worlds, with a default non-trivial implementation *and* the ability to hotswap out implementations at will on the mock just by changing the relevant function field.